# Class instantiation with a dictionary parameter and class variables with default values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a class whose `__init__()` takes a dictionary parameter. Each key in this dictionary corresponds to an instance variable. The instance variables have default values should we create this object without some or all of the dictionary keys. I have this coded as such:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, param1, dict_param):
        self.param1 = param1
        if 'key1' in dict_param:
            self.key1 = dict_param['key1']
        else:
            self.key1 = 10.0  # some default value
        # possibly more instance variable / dictionary key assignments
```

So this works fine, but in reality I have 8 such dictionary key / class variable assignments and 8 default values.

How can I loop through my dictionary keys and assign them to the instance variables?  I'm looking for something like:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, param1, dict_param):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.key1 = 10.0  # set default value
        # more defaults...

        for key in dict_param.keys():
            if object has class_variable key:
               assign class_variable param[key]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
def __init__(self, param1, dict_param):
    self.param1 = param1
    self.key1 = 10.0  # set default value
    # more defaults...

    for key, value in dict_param.iteritems():
        if hasattr(self, key):
           setattr(self, key, value)
```

You could also create a dictionary of the default values and use that:

```
def __init__(self, param1, dict_param):
    self.param1 = param1
    default_vals = {
        'key1': 'default 1',
        'key2': 'default 2',
        'etc': 'and so on'
    }

    for key, value in default_vals.iteritems():
        setattr(self, key, dict_param.get(key, value))
```

This approach lets you use `dict.get` to grab the value from `dict_param` if it exists, or use the value from `default_vals` if no value is provided in `dict_param`.  Also, depending on where the defaults come from, you could define `default_vals` at the class level (that is, outside `__init__` but inside the class) or globally in the module.

Note that you do not have any class variables here.  You have instance variables.

Comment: +1. you could also use `**kwargs` instead of `dict_param` if you wanted to pass keys/values as keyword arguments.

Comment: In the second code block would 'default_vals = ' not be 'self.default_vals = ' since after you are using setattr(self, ?

Comment: @Scott: No.  `setattr` will set the individual attribute (key1, key2, etc.) on `self`.  You could use `self.default_vals = ...` but then you'd have toi use `self.default_vals.iteritems()` later.  Also this would store the default value dict on each instance in addition to that instance's own values for the individual attributes, which would create a bit of clutter.

Comment: @BrenBarn I like the second method you proposed but it will give me a bunch of unresolved attribute references.  My code runs because of the defaults or dictionary I pass in.  Should I not care about the unresolved attributes or should I set them to None?

Comment: @BrenBarn This is the ide (PyCharm) letting me know of possible problems.  Since I haven't explicitly named self.key1 in __init__() the ide highlights everywhere that I make use of self.key1.  Since your solution has either defaults or dict_param feeding self it all works out and the code runs.

Comment: @Scott: Ah, I see.  I'm not sure how to get around that; I don't know much about PyCharm.  In general, any system that "automates" setting attributes in this way will run into problems with those sorts of IDE features, because the IDE can't know about attributes that are set programmtically without actually running your code.  Some IDEs have ways to "turn off" that behavior in certain sections, but I don't know if PyCharm does or if it would even work in this situation.  If you're going to use dynamically-set attributes like your question asks for, you probably need to ignore those IDE errors.

Comment: @BrenBarn Got it.  I wouldn't want to turn that off in general as it comes in handy.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative - here, `__init__` doesn't take a `dict` but you can send it a dictionary throughout *keyword arguments*.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self, key1=10.0, key2=5):
...             self.key1 = key1
...             self.key2 = key2
...
>>> a = A(**{'key2': 3})
>>> a.key1
10.0
>>> a.key2
3
```